# App not installed Error for api above 21

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have problem with my application apk, can't install in devices that running android api above 21. 
I'm using

Android Studio 2.2 , Gradle plugin 2.2.0 , BuildTools 24.0.2

tnx in advance

Comment: what about sdk version?

Comment: compile sdk is 23

Comment: is your target sdk matching compile sdk? target sdk should also be 21 or greater.

Comment: yes, the target sdk also is 23

Comment: can you put some error code in console and whether you can install normally in version below 21?

Comment: My problem is this error occur during installing apk. and don't show any log.

Comment: Can you add build.gradle to your question?

Comment: try install it via adb

Comment: i have the same problem here, have you made it?

Comment: @Jacky yes, read my [checked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40976115/2999385)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle plugin version 2.2.0 is not compatible with BuildTools 24.0.2 !
changing BuildTools to 23.0.2 fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not Your case, but App not installed error occurs also when You are using several accounts in the same device and in one of accounts somehow older version of App You are trying to install, still exists.

Comment: No, I tried 3-4 devices and delete previous version of app but not working!